# Opened file as variable not defined in other method

Tags: python, file

I am opening a file called summary and then calling a recursive method. I need to be able to write to the file at one point in the recursive method but I am getting an error: 'global name 'summary' is not defined. I think it's something to do with the scope but I don't know how to fix it.

My code is structured as follows:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w+') as summary:
  summary.write('Summary\n')

  for entry in file_map:
    add_item(entry, '', summary, 1)

def add_item(entry, tree, file, isTrue):
  summary.write('Hello World')
  # file.write('Hello World') doesn't work either 
  # but this wouldn't be ideal since this value changes in different recursive calls
```

Comment: timgeb How would it be closed if it's still being called within the scope of the 'with'

Comment: sorry, you are right. You should get a `NameError` that `add_item` is not defined.

Comment: but it would be easier to help you if your code snippet was runnable. I changed `'path/to/file'` to `'test'` and `file_map` to `['1', '2']`.

Comment: timgeb I got it to work. I had a main() method that all this was happening in but it's scope wasn't global. When putting all that code in my 'if __name__ == '__main__' method, it worked.

Comment: Good! Next time, in order to avoid confusion and increase the likelyhood that you get an answer, prodive a [MCVE], in particular with code that potential answerers could run by copy pasting it.

Comment: Will do and thanks :)